# Optimizing java array method

Tags: java, arrays

I got a question, how do i make this code more efficient? currently the result is 22. How can I get 22 as the same result whilst using the same method.

```
public static int mystery(int[] a) {
    int r = Math.abs(a[0]-a[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length -1; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(a[i]-a[i+1]) > r){
            r = Math.abs(a[i]-a[i+1]);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] a = {1,3,-10,12,3,20}
    System.out.println(mystery(a));
}
```

Comment: It would help to know what your code does rather than have us examine it before figuring it out. Especially with a method name of `mystery`

Comment: Why do you think it's inefficient? What's your performance target?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @chevybow looks for the biggest diff between two consecutive elements in the array.

Comment: This code runs in O(n) and it's doing the calculation in one pass on the array. It requires O(1) space. You can't do it in less...

Comment: You can start with `i=1`, and you could store the `Math.abs(...)` in a variable instead of potentially calculating it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two improvements, although it probably won't matter much in total execution time.

The first one. In the code below we start the for loop at `1` instead of `0` and eliminate the `a.length - 1` part, we also have to change the `a[i]-a[i+1]` part below that to `a[i - 1] - a[i]` to work with our new range of numbers. So that's one math operation less.

```
public static int mystery() {
    int[] a = { 1, 3, -10, 12, 3, 20 };
    int r = Math.abs(a[0] - a[1]);
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(a[i - 1] - a[i]) > r) {
            r = Math.abs(a[i - 1] - a[i]);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

The second one, you're calling `Math.abs(a[i]-a[i+1])` twice, but you can also store it in a variable and then just use that to compare & assign if it meets your criteria. Below is the code for that, combined with the improvement in the previous code block.

```
public static int mystery() {
    int[] a = { 1, 3, -10, 12, 3, 20 };
    int r = Math.abs(a[0] - a[1]);
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        int newR = Math.abs(a[i - 1] - a[i]);
        if (newR > r) {
            r = newR;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```